# IE9 fadeIn not working

Tags: jquery

Here's the code

```
$('body').fadeIn(1500, 'easeOutCubic');
```

Here's [an example](http://www.trimeragroup.com/)

It works in EVERY OTHER BROWSER, why not IE9 :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check if this works for you http://www.kevinleary.net/wp-samples/ie-fade-problems.php